# C# MVC: Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm getting an error when I try to run my project with IIS:

> Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>
> System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the
> runtime.

My project is written in C# MVC with framework 4.6.2.

Here is the exception image:

[image]

Comment: hi did you find the solution